# wlan0 still uses wrong driver?

Tags: networking, drivers, realtek-wireless, modprobe, dkms

I installed the driver from https://github.com/vincent-t/rt8192cu_dkms
which installs the `8192cu` driver (replacing the native `rtl8192cu` driver) which should work with my `TP-LINK TL-WN821N v4.1` USB wifi adapter.

So far my Skype (on Ubuntu 15.04) works (meaning I have internet access and I could connect to my wireless hotspot)
However I cannot load any homepage (I can ping 8.8.8.8 (google dns)) but
cannot load any homepage?

```
lsmod | grep rtl
```

returns nothing (which is good, meaning no realtek drivers `rtl*` drivers are loaded

```
lsmod | grep 81
```

returns `8192cu` which shows that the new driver is loaded.

However

```
lshw -C network
```

returns

```
*-network
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 1
       bus info: usb@1:4
       logical name: wlan0
       serial: f4:f2:6d:18:f1:5b
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8192cu ip=192.168.0.103 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
```

which shows that `driver=rtl8192cu` loads the old driver?
I dont get it, either that is strange and I have to manually say that wlan0 should use `8192cu` driver. Or my internet connection is corrupted?

Anyone some idea?

Comment: You need to blacklist rtl8192cu, or at least make sure it is blacklisted, otherwise both will get loaded. Check the output of `grep 8192 /etc/modprobe.d/*`. On the second though, rtl8192cu might be just an alias.

Comment: even when the git repo driver installes a file `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rtl-wlan-drivers.conf` by doing ``echo "install rtl8192cu /bin/false\ninstall rtl8192c_common /bin/false\ninstall rtlwifi /bin/false\ninstall rtl8xxxu /bin/false" | tee /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-native-rtl-wlan-drivers.conf``

Comment: I was hoping you'd add that to the question.

Comment: I see that since my skype works but not DNS resolving (loading a page) , there is something fishy with DNS, I tried to add the DNS IPs of my ISP in the network manager, but did not help

Comment: Try 192.168.0.1 as a DNS server, or whatever the router's IP is.

Comment: @Gabriel as a test lets try setting the DNS server to google DNS manually in the /etc/resolv.conf file and see if that helps. To do so open a terminal and type the command "sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf" then delete any lines that start with the word nameserver and simply add a single line saying "nameserver 8.8.8.8"

Comment: @mikewhatever It's quite probable that it is an alias at a guess the 8192cu driver is probably a patched version of the rtl8192cu codebase and the patch adds the support without actually changing the name it uses internally perhaps.

Comment: I added the ``nameserver 8.8.8.8`` line still got now internet (skype is working), what the hack is wrong with my DNS i dont get it, thanks for the help

Comment: sudo dpkg-reconfigure resolveconf seemed to do the trick
ans I have a connection now! finally